# Cannot install VCD file

Tags: javascript, win-universal-app, uwp, cortana, xbox-one

I am attempting to integrate Cortana into my UWP. The first step to this, is "installing" the the VCD file. The below snippet works fine on Windows 10, but causes an error when deployed to Xbox. Specifically, the "installCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync" is what is failing. Is there another way to install the VCD on Xbox? Or, is this a bug that is yet to be fixed?

```
return wap.current.installedLocation.getFileAsync("vdmvoicecommands.xml").then(function (file) {
           return voiceCommandManager.installCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync(file);
       }, function (er) {
           console.error('error file vdmvoicecommands.xml', er);
       }).then(function () {
           var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;

           var commandSetName = "VDM_" + language.toLowerCase();

           var commansets = Windows.ApplicationModel.VoiceCommands.VoiceCommandDefinitionManager.installedCommandDefinitions;
           if (commansets.hasKey(commandSetName)) {
               console.log("VCD loaded !");
           } else {
               console.log("VCD not installed yet?");
           }
       }, function (ee) {
           console.warn("installCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync error", ee);
       });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VoiceCommands APIs are currently not supported on Xbox. You can find list of UWP APIs that are currently not supported on Xbox [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt693377.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Vivek. Did you (MSFT) just update that list? I am sure that Cortana was not on there a week ago, when I looked.

Comment: I can attest to that. That was the first page I went when I saw this question :) Better late than never